# input type=search not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web app.  Uses jQuery, bootstrap and Kendo UI.  I have a FilterBox input for searching a Kendo Grid - I had the `type="text"` originally in the markup but i changed this to take advantage of html5 type="seacrh" to get samll x in the field when user types - but for some reason this is not working?  I am testing this in chrome and I did a Ctrl and F5 to make sure I fully reloaded the page?

input field current looks like:

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="search" placeholder="Type to Filter...">
```

and in my js I have the following:

```
    var searchTextBox = $("#txtSearch");

    searchTextBox.on("change keyup paste mouseup", function () {
       // search logic
    });
```

Comment: did you check your browser if it supports html5?

Comment: To see that X in input, you need to type in first .. did you do that?

Comment: yeah i started typing in the box - no x appeared I am using Chrome version 35.0.1916.153

Comment: Can you share if you did write any CSS for the input?

Answer (score 0):

I am also on 35.0.1916.153 m and its working please check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vMu3B/

```
var searchTextBox = $("#txtSearch");

    searchTextBox.on("change keyup paste mouseup", function () {
        var back = ["#ff0000","blue","gray"];
        var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
            $("#divtest").css('background',rand);
    });
```

Comment: Very strange - this is working for me in js fiddle but not in my site - very strange

Comment: check your console for errors or may be just make this as the code and check if it works on your page if this fiddle works then error is in your side not jquery

Comment: restart your server i guess?

Answer (score -3):

I think you are using .on in wrong way. According to documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ it should be:

```
<div class="searchbox">
<input id="txtSearch" type="search" placeholder="Type to Filter...">
</div>

var searchTextBox = $(".searchbox");

    searchTextBox.on("#txtSearch","change keyup paste mouseup", function () {
       // search logic
    });
```